# LBFGS: Accuracy of Hessian approximation

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

Does anybody know how useful LBFGS is for estimating the Hessian matrix in the case of many (>10 000) dimensions? When running scipy's implementation on a simple 100D quadratic form the algorithm does already seem to struggle. Are there any general results about special cases (i.e. a dominant diagonal) in which the approximated Hessian is reasonably trustworthy?

Finally, one immediate drawback in scipy's implementation to me seems that the initial estimate of the Hessian is the identity matrix which might lead to a slower convergence. Do you know how important this effect is, i.e. how would the algorithm be affected if I would have a good idea of what the diagonal elements would be?

Here are two sets of example plots for a rather diagonal dominant form, as well as for a case with strong off-diagonals. The first one shows the original covariance matrix and the latter one gives the approximated results using m=50 and m=500.

[image: a=0.2: Original covariance matrix]
[image: a=0.2: Reconstruction using m=50]
[image: a=0.2: Reconstruction using m=500]

[image: a=3.0: Original covariance matrix]
[image: a=3.0: Reconstruction using m=50]
[image: a=3.0: Reconstruction using m=500]

Code for running the experiment:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Parameters
ndims = 100 # Dimensions for our problem
a = .2 # Relative importance of non-diagonal elements in covariance
m = 500 # Number of updates we allow in lbfgs
x0=1*np.random.rand(ndims) # Initial starting point for LBFGS

# Generate covariance matrix
A = np.matrix([np.random.randn(ndims) + np.random.randn(1)*a for i in range(ndims)])
A = A*np.transpose(A)
D_half = np.diag(np.diag(A)**(-0.5))
cov= D_half*A*D_half
invcov = np.linalg.inv(cov)
assert(np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(cov) > 0))

# Define quadratic form and its derivative
def gauss(x,invcov):
    res = 0.5*x.T@invcov@x
    return res[0,0]

def gaussgrad(x,invcov):
    res = np.asarray(x.T@invcov)
    return res[0]

# Put function in lambda shape
fgauss = lambda x: gauss(x,invcov=invcov)
fprimegauss = lambda x: gaussgrad(x,invcov=invcov)

# Run the lbfgs variant and retrieve the inverse Hessian approximation
x, f, d, s, y = fmin_l_bfgs_b(func=fgauss,x0=x0,fprime=fprimegauss,m=m,approx_grad=False)
invhess = LbfgsInvHess(s, y)

# Plot the results
plt.imshow(cov)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

plt.imshow(invhess.todense(),vmin=np.min(cov),vmax=np.max(cov))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

plt.imshow(invhess.todense()-cov)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

As scipy does not give the vectors from which the Hessian is reconstructed we need to call a marginally modified function (based on scipy.optimize.lbfgsb.py):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, asarray, float64, zeros
from scipy.optimize import _lbfgsb
from scipy.optimize.optimize import (MemoizeJac, OptimizeResult,
                       _check_unknown_options, _prepare_scalar_function)
from scipy.optimize._constraints import old_bound_to_new

from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

__all__ = ['fmin_l_bfgs_b', 'LbfgsInvHessProduct']


def fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0, fprime=None, args=(),
                  approx_grad=0,
                  bounds=None, m=10, factr=1e7, pgtol=1e-5,
                  epsilon=1e-8,
                  iprint=-1, maxfun=15000, maxiter=15000, disp=None,
                  callback=None, maxls=20):
    """
    Minimize a function func using the L-BFGS-B algorithm.
    Parameters
    ----------
    func : callable f(x,*args)
        Function to minimize.
    x0 : ndarray
        Initial guess.
    fprime : callable fprime(x,*args), optional
        The gradient of `func`. If None, then `func` returns the function
        value and the gradient (``f, g = func(x, *args)``), unless
        `approx_grad` is True in which case `func` returns only ``f``.
    args : sequence, optional
        Arguments to pass to `func` and `fprime`.
    approx_grad : bool, optional
        Whether to approximate the gradient numerically (in which case
        `func` returns only the function value).
    bounds : list, optional
        ``(min, max)`` pairs for each element in ``x``, defining
        the bounds on that parameter. Use None or +-inf for one of ``min`` or
        ``max`` when there is no bound in that direction.
    m : int, optional
        The maximum number of variable metric corrections
        used to define the limited memory matrix. (The limited memory BFGS
        method does not store the full hessian but uses this many terms in an
        approximation to it.)
    factr : float, optional
        The iteration stops when
        ``(f^k - f^{k+1})/max{|f^k|,|f^{k+1}|,1} <= factr * eps``,
        where ``eps`` is the machine precision, which is automatically
        generated by the code. Typical values for `factr` are: 1e12 for
        low accuracy; 1e7 for moderate accuracy; 10.0 for extremely
        high accuracy. See Notes for relationship to `ftol`, which is exposed
        (instead of `factr`) by the `scipy.optimize.minimize` interface to
        L-BFGS-B.
    pgtol : float, optional
        The iteration will stop when
        ``max{|proj g_i | i = 1, ..., n} <= pgtol``
        where ``pg_i`` is the i-th component of the projected gradient.
    epsilon : float, optional
        Step size used when `approx_grad` is True, for numerically
        calculating the gradient
    iprint : int, optional
        Controls the frequency of output. ``iprint < 0`` means no output;
        ``iprint = 0``    print only one line at the last iteration;
        ``0 < iprint < 99`` print also f and ``|proj g|`` every iprint iterations;
        ``iprint = 99``   print details of every iteration except n-vectors;
        ``iprint = 100``  print also the changes of active set and final x;
        ``iprint > 100``  print details of every iteration including x and g.
    disp : int, optional
        If zero, then no output. If a positive number, then this over-rides
        `iprint` (i.e., `iprint` gets the value of `disp`).
    maxfun : int, optional
        Maximum number of function evaluations.
    maxiter : int, optional
        Maximum number of iterations.
    callback : callable, optional
        Called after each iteration, as ``callback(xk)``, where ``xk`` is the
        current parameter vector.
    maxls : int, optional
        Maximum number of line search steps (per iteration). Default is 20.
    Returns
    -------
    x : array_like
        Estimated position of the minimum.
    f : float
        Value of `func` at the minimum.
    d : dict
        Information dictionary.
        * d['warnflag'] is
          - 0 if converged,
          - 1 if too many function evaluations or too many iterations,
          - 2 if stopped for another reason, given in d['task']
        * d['grad'] is the gradient at the minimum (should be 0 ish)
        * d['funcalls'] is the number of function calls made.
        * d['nit'] is the number of iterations.
    See also
    --------
    minimize: Interface to minimization algorithms for multivariate
        functions. See the 'L-BFGS-B' `method` in particular. Note that the
        `ftol` option is made available via that interface, while `factr` is
        provided via this interface, where `factr` is the factor multiplying
        the default machine floating-point precision to arrive at `ftol`:
        ``ftol = factr * numpy.finfo(float).eps``.
    Notes
    -----
    License of L-BFGS-B (FORTRAN code):
    The version included here (in fortran code) is 3.0
    (released April 25, 2011). It was written by Ciyou Zhu, Richard Byrd,
    and Jorge Nocedal <nocedal@ece.nwu.edu>. It carries the following
    condition for use:
    This software is freely available, but we expect that all publications
    describing work using this software, or all commercial products using it,
    quote at least one of the references given below. This software is released
    under the BSD License.
    References
    ----------
    * R. H. Byrd, P. Lu and J. Nocedal. A Limited Memory Algorithm for Bound
      Constrained Optimization, (1995), SIAM Journal on Scientific and
      Statistical Computing, 16, 5, pp. 1190-1208.
    * C. Zhu, R. H. Byrd and J. Nocedal. L-BFGS-B: Algorithm 778: L-BFGS-B,
      FORTRAN routines for large scale bound constrained optimization (1997),
      ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 23, 4, pp. 550 - 560.
    * J.L. Morales and J. Nocedal. L-BFGS-B: Remark on Algorithm 778: L-BFGS-B,
      FORTRAN routines for large scale bound constrained optimization (2011),
      ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, 38, 1.
    """
    # handle fprime/approx_grad
    if approx_grad:
        fun = func
        jac = None
    elif fprime is None:
        fun = MemoizeJac(func)
        jac = fun.derivative
    else:
        fun = func
        jac = fprime

    # build options
    if disp is None:
        disp = iprint
    opts = {'disp': disp,
            'iprint': iprint,
            'maxcor': m,
            'ftol': factr * np.finfo(float).eps,
            'gtol': pgtol,
            'eps': epsilon,
            'maxfun': maxfun,
            'maxiter': maxiter,
            'callback': callback,
            'maxls': maxls}

    res, s, y = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
                           **opts)
    d = {'grad': res['jac'],
         'task': res['message'],
         'funcalls': res['nfev'],
         'nit': res['nit'],
         'warnflag': res['status']}
    f = res['fun']
    x = res['x']
    
    return x, f, d, s, y


def _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=(), jac=None, bounds=None,
                     disp=None, maxcor=10, ftol=2.2204460492503131e-09,
                     gtol=1e-5, eps=1e-8, maxfun=15000, maxiter=15000,
                     iprint=-1, callback=None, maxls=20,
                     finite_diff_rel_step=None, **unknown_options):
    """
    Minimize a scalar function of one or more variables using the L-BFGS-B
    algorithm.
    Options
    -------
    disp : None or int
        If `disp is None` (the default), then the supplied version of `iprint`
        is used. If `disp is not None`, then it overrides the supplied version
        of `iprint` with the behaviour you outlined.
    maxcor : int
        The maximum number of variable metric corrections used to
        define the limited memory matrix. (The limited memory BFGS
        method does not store the full hessian but uses this many terms
        in an approximation to it.)
    ftol : float
        The iteration stops when ``(f^k -
        f^{k+1})/max{|f^k|,|f^{k+1}|,1} <= ftol``.
    gtol : float
        The iteration will stop when ``max{|proj g_i | i = 1, ..., n}
        <= gtol`` where ``pg_i`` is the i-th component of the
        projected gradient.
    eps : float or ndarray
        If `jac is None` the absolute step size used for numerical
        approximation of the jacobian via forward differences.
    maxfun : int
        Maximum number of function evaluations.
    maxiter : int
        Maximum number of iterations.
    iprint : int, optional
        Controls the frequency of output. ``iprint < 0`` means no output;
        ``iprint = 0``    print only one line at the last iteration;
        ``0 < iprint < 99`` print also f and ``|proj g|`` every iprint iterations;
        ``iprint = 99``   print details of every iteration except n-vectors;
        ``iprint = 100``  print also the changes of active set and final x;
        ``iprint > 100``  print details of every iteration including x and g.
    callback : callable, optional
        Called after each iteration, as ``callback(xk)``, where ``xk`` is the
        current parameter vector.
    maxls : int, optional
        Maximum number of line search steps (per iteration). Default is 20.
    finite_diff_rel_step : None or array_like, optional
        If `jac in ['2-point', '3-point', 'cs']` the relative step size to
        use for numerical approximation of the jacobian. The absolute step
        size is computed as ``h = rel_step * sign(x0) * max(1, abs(x0))``,
        possibly adjusted to fit into the bounds. For ``method='3-point'``
        the sign of `h` is ignored. If None (default) then step is selected
        automatically.
    Notes
    -----
    The option `ftol` is exposed via the `scipy.optimize.minimize` interface,
    but calling `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` directly exposes `factr`. The
    relationship between the two is ``ftol = factr * numpy.finfo(float).eps``.
    I.e., `factr` multiplies the default machine floating-point precision to
    arrive at `ftol`.
    """
    #_check_unknown_options(unknown_options)
    m = maxcor
    pgtol = gtol
    factr = ftol / np.finfo(float).eps

    x0 = asarray(x0).ravel()
    n, = x0.shape

    if bounds is None:
        bounds = [(None, None)] * n
    if len(bounds) != n:
        raise ValueError('length of x0 != length of bounds')

    # unbounded variables must use None, not +-inf, for optimizer to work properly
    bounds = [(None if l == -np.inf else l, None if u == np.inf else u) for l, u in bounds]
    # LBFGSB is sent 'old-style' bounds, 'new-style' bounds are required by
    # approx_derivative and ScalarFunction
    new_bounds = old_bound_to_new(bounds)

    # check bounds
    if (new_bounds[0] > new_bounds[1]).any():
        raise ValueError("LBFGSB - one of the lower bounds is greater than an upper bound.")

    # initial vector must lie within the bounds. Otherwise ScalarFunction and
    # approx_derivative will cause problems
    x0 = np.clip(x0, new_bounds[0], new_bounds[1])

    if disp is not None:
        if disp == 0:
            iprint = -1
        else:
            iprint = disp

    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
                                  bounds=new_bounds,
                                  finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step)

    func_and_grad = sf.fun_and_grad

    fortran_int = _lbfgsb.types.intvar.dtype

    nbd = zeros(n, fortran_int)
    low_bnd = zeros(n, float64)
    upper_bnd = zeros(n, float64)
    bounds_map = {(None, None): 0,
                  (1, None): 1,
                  (1, 1): 2,
                  (None, 1): 3}
    for i in range(0, n):
        l, u = bounds[i]
        if l is not None:
            low_bnd[i] = l
            l = 1
        if u is not None:
            upper_bnd[i] = u
            u = 1
        nbd[i] = bounds_map[l, u]

    if not maxls > 0:
        raise ValueError('maxls must be positive.')

    x = array(x0, float64)
    f = array(0.0, float64)
    g = zeros((n,), float64)
    wa = zeros(2*m*n + 5*n + 11*m*m + 8*m, float64)
    iwa = zeros(3*n, fortran_int)
    task = zeros(1, 'S60')
    csave = zeros(1, 'S60')
    lsave = zeros(4, fortran_int)
    isave = zeros(44, fortran_int)
    dsave = zeros(29, float64)

    task[:] = 'START'

    n_iterations = 0

    while 1:
        # x, f, g, wa, iwa, task, csave, lsave, isave, dsave = \
        _lbfgsb.setulb(m, x, low_bnd, upper_bnd, nbd, f, g, factr,
                       pgtol, wa, iwa, task, iprint, csave, lsave,
                       isave, dsave, maxls)
        task_str = task.tobytes()
        if task_str.startswith(b'FG'):
            # The minimization routine wants f and g at the current x.
            # Note that interruptions due to maxfun are postponed
            # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
            # Overwrite f and g:
            f, g = func_and_grad(x)
        elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
            # new iteration
            n_iterations += 1
            if callback is not None:
                callback(np.copy(x))

            if n_iterations >= maxiter:
                task[:] = 'STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT'
            elif sf.nfev > maxfun:
                task[:] = ('STOP: TOTAL NO. of f AND g EVALUATIONS '
                           'EXCEEDS LIMIT')
        else:
            break

    task_str = task.tobytes().strip(b'\x00').strip()
    if task_str.startswith(b'CONV'):
        warnflag = 0
    elif sf.nfev > maxfun or n_iterations >= maxiter:
        warnflag = 1
    else:
        warnflag = 2

    # These two portions of the workspace are described in the mainlb
    # subroutine in lbfgsb.f. See line 363.
    s = wa[0: m*n].reshape(m, n)
    y = wa[m*n: 2*m*n].reshape(m, n)
    print(x.shape)
    
    

    # See lbfgsb.f line 160 for this portion of the workspace.
    # isave(31) = the total number of BFGS updates prior the current iteration;
    n_bfgs_updates = isave[30]

    n_corrs = min(n_bfgs_updates, maxcor)
    inv_hess = LbfgsInvHess(s[:n_corrs], y[:n_corrs])

    task_str = task_str.decode()
    return OptimizeResult(fun=f, jac=g, nfev=sf.nfev,
                          njev=sf.ngev,
                          nit=n_iterations, status=warnflag, message=task_str,
                          x=x, success=(warnflag == 0), hess_inv=inv_hess), s[:n_corrs], y[:n_corrs]
    

class LbfgsInvHess(LinearOperator):
    """Linear operator for the L-BFGS approximate inverse Hessian.
    This operator computes the product of a vector with the approximate inverse
    of the Hessian of the objective function, using the L-BFGS limited
    memory approximation to the inverse Hessian, accumulated during the
    optimization.
    Objects of this class implement the ``scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator``
    interface.
    Parameters
    ----------
    sk : array_like, shape=(n_corr, n)
        Array of `n_corr` most recent updates to the solution vector.
        (See [1]).
    yk : array_like, shape=(n_corr, n)
        Array of `n_corr` most recent updates to the gradient. (See [1]).
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] Nocedal, Jorge. "Updating quasi-Newton matrices with limited
       storage." Mathematics of computation 35.151 (1980): 773-782.
    """

    def __init__(self, sk, yk):
        """Construct the operator."""
        if sk.shape != yk.shape or sk.ndim != 2:
            raise ValueError('sk and yk must have matching shape, (n_corrs, n)')
        n_corrs, n = sk.shape

        super().__init__(dtype=np.float64, shape=(n, n))

        self.sk = sk
        self.yk = yk
        self.n_corrs = n_corrs
        self.rho = 1 / np.einsum('ij,ij->i', sk, yk)

    def _matvec(self, x):
        """Efficient matrix-vector multiply with the BFGS matrices.
        This calculation is described in Section (4) of [1].
        Parameters
        ----------
        x : ndarray
            An array with shape (n,) or (n,1).
        Returns
        -------
        y : ndarray
            The matrix-vector product
        """
        s, y, n_corrs, rho = self.sk, self.yk, self.n_corrs, self.rho
        q = np.array(x, dtype=self.dtype, copy=True)
        if q.ndim == 2 and q.shape[1] == 1:
            q = q.reshape(-1)

        alpha = np.empty(n_corrs)

        for i in range(n_corrs-1, -1, -1):
            alpha[i] = rho[i] * np.dot(s[i], q)
            q = q - alpha[i]*y[i]

        r = q
        for i in range(n_corrs):
            beta = rho[i] * np.dot(y[i], r)
            r = r + s[i] * (alpha[i] - beta)

        return r

    def todense(self):
        """Return a dense array representation of this operator.
        Returns
        -------
        arr : ndarray, shape=(n, n)
            An array with the same shape and containing
            the same data represented by this `LinearOperator`.
        """
        s, y, n_corrs, rho = self.sk, self.yk, self.n_corrs, self.rho
        I = np.eye(*self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
        Hk = I

        for i in range(n_corrs):
            A1 = I - s[i][:, np.newaxis] * y[i][np.newaxis, :] * rho[i]
            A2 = I - y[i][:, np.newaxis] * s[i][np.newaxis, :] * rho[i]

            Hk = np.dot(A1, np.dot(Hk, A2)) + (rho[i] * s[i][:, np.newaxis] *
                                                        s[i][np.newaxis, :])
        return Hk
```

Edit: Typo in code.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you need to approximate a Hessian of a quadratic form.  Good large-scale QP solvers are readily available and don't need such exercises. I would worry about other things.

Comment: I need a sparse representation of the Hessian of a rather messy and high dimensional (d=10^4-10^7) likelihood which is fed into a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo algorithm to sample from this distribution. The quadratic form here is just chosen for this example in order to test the LBFGS accuracy.

Comment: You may want to look into automatic differentiation to generate the exact sparse Hessian.