# How to obtain accurate standard errors of logit estimation in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

Previously I tried

```
opt1 = minimize(logit, args = (df), x0=x_start,method = 'L-BFGS-B')
hessinv1 = opt1.hess_inv.todense()
hessinvm1 = np.asmatrix(hessinv1)
diag1 = np.sqrt(np.diagonal(hessinvm1))
```

However, it turns out that this Hessian matrix is very unreliable and the results of standard errors are not correct, which has also been mentioned here ([LBFGS: Accuracy of Hessian approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69903606/lbfgs-accuracy-of-hessian-approximation#comment123621875_69903606)). Is there any way that we could obtain the standard error after the optimization process?

Comment: This isn't a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the meantime, I'd propose to provide and use the exact gradient and hessian by algorithmic differentiation, see [jax's AD cookbook](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html) for some examples.

Comment: @joni, thanks for the comment. I tried this, as well as autograd. However, it turns out that they do not work because the objective function that I use for optimization is not a simple function, but a function involving a dataframe, thus it would give me a TypeError: Can't differentiate w.r.t. type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> if I use auto differentiation methods. Do you know how to deal with this?